# "Произведены мероприятия"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Можно ли сказать "произведены мероприятия"?

Answer (score 4):

Так сказать нельзя, поскольку содержанием мероприятия является *не результат* (материальный или изменяющий чьё-л. сознание - напр. *произвести продукт или сенсацию*), а распределённый во времени **процесс**. Поэтому мероприятие не "производят", а **проводят**, организуют (как процесс взамодействия участников) и контролируют его ход на всем временном протяжении.

Неясно даже, что пытались сказать в вашем случае: *проведены мероприятия* или *приняты меры*.

Comment: Из словаря: "МЕРОПРИЯТИЕ, -я; ср. Офиц. Организованное действие или совокупность действий, направленных на осуществление определённой цели".  А осуществление цели - это не есть результат?

Comment: С ответом согласен, но предполагаю, что ход мысли у Ирины был таков: мероприятие это действие, произведены действия – произведены мероприятия.

Comment: спасибо за комментарии, все ясно!

Comment: Что касается употребления глагола "производить" по отношению к действию. Проведение мероприятия заключается не в произведении связанных с его ходом множественных действий, а в **управлении** ими, причём сами действия обычно совершаются не теми, кто проводит мероприятие, а участниками мероприятия. Поэтому осуществление мероприятия не сводимо к произведению действий.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: **проведены мероприятия**.

**Провести:** осуществить ряд направленных действий, имеющих определенную **цель**. Совокупность этих действий имеет название: провести **урок**, провести **соревнование** или другое **мероприятие.**

**Произвести**: **создать** реальный предмет в результате осуществления ряда действий. Произвести выстрел (осуществить выстрел).

Создать (осуществить) урок, соревнование или мероприятие нельзя.

Глаголы отличаются приставкой ИЗ, которая и определяет рождение или создание предмета, приставка ПРО обозначает **протекание процесса во времени.**

Comment: "Призвести действия" не вписывается в эту схему, верно?

Comment: У сочетания слишком обобщенный смысл: произвести действия по ремонту дороги - отремонтировать дорогу.

Comment: Произвести действия по ремонту дороги – ремонтировать дорогу, а не отремонтировать ее.

Comment: Но это же  совершенный вид глагола. Вот ещё  обычный канцелярский пример:  потребитель вправе обратиться в суд с требованиями  произвести действия по ремонту балкона (отремонтировать балкон).

Comment: "Но это же совершенный вид глагола" - не доказательство, "Начать' - тоже совершенный вид, а результата нет... Канцелярский пример - частный случай. Вот противоположный пример: **произвести** следственные действия - это **провести** следствие.

Comment: Обыск проводят и производят, как и следствие.  Например: Статья 182. Основания и порядок производства обыска. Это такие МЕРОПРИЯТИЯ, которые ставят своей целью получение реального (конкретного) РЕЗУЛЬТАТА. - найти орудия преступления, предметы, документы и ценности, которые могут иметь значение для уголовного дела.